# RSpec test of Rails model class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method in my model

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_announcements
    @announcements = Announcement.where("starts <= :start_date and ends >= :end_date and disabled = false",
      {:start_date => "#{Date.today}", :end_date => "#{Date.today}"})
    return @announcements 
  end
end
```

I am trying to write rspec for this method, as i am new to rspec cant proceed

```
describe ".get_announcements" do
  before { @result = FactoryGirl.create(:announcement) }
  it "return announcements" do 

  end
end
```

Please help

Comment: What is making you confuse ? Please tell us that.

Comment: I dont know how to proceed             before { @ans = Announcement.get_announcements}  and in it block i passed following expect(@ans).to equal(@result), as am giving Announcement.get_announcements its bringing <ActiveRecord::Relation:105375450> => []

Answer (score 1):

Solution for my question

```
describe ".get_announcements" do
    before { @result = FactoryGirl.create(:announcement) }
    it "return announcement" do
      Announcement.get_announcements.should_not be_empty
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
describe ".get_announcements" do
  let!(:announcements) { [FactoryGirl.create!(:announcement)] }
  it "returns announcements" do
    expect(Announcement.get_announcements).to eq announcements
  end
end
```

Note the use of `let!` to immediately (not lazily) assign to `announcements`.

Does the class method really need to define an instance variable? If not, it could be refactored to:

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_announcements
    Announcement.where("starts <= :start_date and ends >= :end_date and disabled = false",
  {:start_date => "#{Date.today}", :end_date => "#{Date.today}"})
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer also worked fine for me, Thanks @zetetic